# results to be obtained as per the index in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here is my code  to display the counts of results obtained

My controller looks like this

```
$data['present'][]= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);
```

my model looks like this

```
public function present_report_by_empid($user_id = null,$date = null) 
 {


   $temp = explode("-",$date);
   $query='tbl_attendance.date_in';
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.attendance_status', 1);
   $this->db->where('tbl_attendance.user_id', $user_id);
   $this->db->where("YEAR(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[0]);
   $this->db->where("MONTH(tbl_attendance.date_in)",$temp[1]);
   $result = $this->db->get('tbl_attendance')->result_array();
   $count=count($result); //counts number of rows
   return $count;
}
```

view looks like this

```
 <?php foreach($present as $key1 => $row){?>
            <?php echo $row;?>
  <?php }?>
```

when i use my code am getting result like this 
[image]

but i want my result to be like this 
[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, please elaborate it more. Also You should use `$this->db->get('tbl_attendance')->num_rows();` to get number of rows

Comment: this code return same as what `num_rows()` returns

Comment: Exactly, but you're using long method to do same thing.

Comment: k leave about that can we talk about getting result

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're building up the `$data['present']` array with everyone's data first so you might want to do it like this :-

`$data['present'][$v_employee->user_id] = $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);`

In the view you would pass in the `$user_id` and then just echo the data for the correct user :-

`<?php echo $present[$user_id] ;?>`

Comment: here am getting like this Message: Undefined variable: user_id

Comment: You need to pass the user_id to the view as a variable. For example:- `$data['user_id'] = $v_employee->user_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data['present'][$v_employee->user_id]= $this->attendance_model->present_report_by_empid($v_employee->user_id,$date);

$empl = array(
//  empl_id => name,
    1 => 'administrator',
    2 => 'siraj',
    3 => 'faizal',
    4 => 'nesru',

)


foreach($empl as $key1 => $row){
    echo $row;
    if (!isset($data['present'][$key1])) {
        echo ' '.$data['present'][$key1];
    } else {
        echo ' - ';
    }
}
```